# C# Svg Library Engine ShapeRendering

Tags: c#, svg, png

Iam trying to convert a vector image(SVG) to PNG. I almost got it working except the final touch which has something todo with Shape Rendering.

I use the following code:

```
public string GeneratePng()
{
SvgDocument SvgDoc = SvgDocument.Open(@"C:\Temp\test.svg");
SvgDoc.Width = 1000;
SvgDoc.Height = 1000;
SvgDoc.ShapeRendering = SvgShapeRendering.GeometricPrecision;
Bitmap bmp = SvgDoc.Draw();
bmp.Save(@"C:\Temp\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
return "done";
}
```

I use the nuget package: **nuget.org/packages/Svg/**
and the following svg file: https://www.w3.org/Icons/SVG/svg-logo-h.svg

The result https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bw9G.png with the edges pixelated. What I except it to do is to smoothen out the edges as stated GeometricPrecision would do.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the package you are using, but my guess is that `GeometrixPrecision` does the opposite of what you think it does. what other options do you have for `ShapeRendering`?

Comment: @TimothyGroote the options are Auto, CrispEdges, GeometricPrecision, Inherit and OptimizeSpeed. If you would recommend the use of a different C# Vector image library I am always open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm used to having WPF handle SVG's for me, heh. so unfortunately, that may not be a valid option for you. The lib you're using seems fairly underdocumented too, which is too bad since it looks like it's pretty extensive. does changing to `CrispEdges` change anything about the appearance in the png?

Comment: @TimothyGroote sadly nothing changes the outcome. It think the library requires something else to affect its "smoothing" filter. Without the proper documentation its looking for a needle...

Comment: @TimothyGroote I think I am onto something. It could also be the Bitmap iam sending my svg to since I use draw on it. InterpolationMode and PixelOffsetMode could be in play here. Will report back my findings.